# how to download a file in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to download a file on button click in angularjs

```
 <button ng-click=downloadfile()>download</button>
```

In controller

```
  $scope.downloadfile=function()
        {
            //
        }
```

which functionality i have to write in downloadfile function could you please explain

Comment: I hope this Usesfull
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215049/how-to-download-file-using-angularjs-and-calling-mvc-api

Answer (score 5):

Write this out in your `downloadFile()` function.

```
    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);        

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv"; //this is an example file to download, use yours

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.downloadFile = function (doc) {

```
        var token = $localStorage.authenticationToken || $sessionStorage.authenticationToken;
        if (token) {
            token = 'Bearer ' + token;
        }

        var url = new $window.URL($location.absUrl()).origin + "/api/voyages/" +
            vm.voyage.id + '/documents/' + doc.id + '?auth=' + token;
        $window.open(url);
    };
```