# Download pdf with Angular

Tags: angularjs

Trying to download a pdf doc with Angular, we wrote this:

```
var _config = { headers : {'Accept' : '*/*'},
                responseType : 'arraybuffer'
              };

var success = function(data, status, header, config) {
   $log.debug('Download resume success - type:' + typeof (data));
   var _contentType = (header('Content-Type'));
   var blob = new Blob([ data ], { type : _contentType });
   var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
   var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
   anchor.attr({
      href : url,
      target : '_blank',
      download : _fileName
   })[0].click();
}
$http.get(_url, _config).success(success).error(error);
```

We've tried all permutations of blob and arraybuffer but `data` always returns as a String with the extended characters 'decoded' which is to say broken.

`_contentType` is always `application/pdf` although we've tried forcing it to `application/octet-stream` as well.

Suggestions and pointers welcomed!

**Update**

This looks to be a bug someplace between Angular (1.3.15 & 1.4.8) and Chrome's (46.0) XMLHttpRequest implementation where response.data is always returned as a 'decoded' string. Neither Firefox (42) nor IE (10) have this problem and all of the solutions below would most likely work (as does or original solution).

I've reported this as a possible bug to both AngularJS & Chrome.

Comment: Here's a guy who did it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23683763/652728

Comment: Yeah, why doesn't this work in straight-up Angular? Seems like it should.

Comment: Any reason you create a link instead of just window.location() it?

Comment: No. Right now we're concentrating on getting the file to the client with the content intact.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to this problem myself a few months back. I had to use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to handle it.

So after you install FileSaver.js have your success function look something like this:

```
function success(response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf"});
    //change download.pdf to the name of whatever you want your file to be
    saveAs(blob, "download.pdf");
}
```

Comment: We've tried FileSaver.js, no difference. One question I have with FileSaver is how do I know the Blob is handled by FileSaver and not by the built-in Blob?

Comment: What are you using in the backend? I also had problems with my node/express server corrupting my zip data. I had to fs.writeFile to a temporary file on the server then 
    res.download(pathOfFile, filename + ".zip"); And that seemed to work.

Comment: Spring is our backend. The file is only modified when it gets to Angular, when we inspect the `data` object. Over the wire it's fine. GET from another Spring server is fine. GET from Postman saves the file to disk and it's uncorrupted. The only time we have trouble is trying to get it download to our Angular client :-(

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Have you logged the data from the response to make sure the data is what you're expecting it to be? And lastly, are you making sure that the MIME type is set to `"application/pdf"`? I also noticed you're using `.success` to handle your http promise, which has been deprecated, which is why I'm asking which version you're using.

Comment: 1.3.x, we've tried 1.4.x and no difference (although we're going to upgrade everything to 1.4.x). Yes, over the wire the data is a pdf file, save it to disk and Acrobat opens it without a problem. Yes, the mime type is always `application/pdf` unless we force it to `octet-stream`.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `console.log` in your success callback to see what the data is?

Comment: Yes, typeof(data) says 'string' which seems to me to be the root cause- that Angular is converting the raw stream to text and mangling the pdf's extended characters.

Comment: That's your problem. Your backend needs to send it as an ArrayBuffer, which type will be object.

Comment: That backend is Java/Spring and sends the raw file as `application/pdf`, what do you mean by 'ArrayBuffer'? Not catching the Response body as a `blob`?

Comment: Mozilla has a really nice article on [ArrayBuffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer). I recall there being problems sending string data that the Blob constructor and Angular just didn't like to play together with. I'll be damned if I can remember the exact reason, but it was the reason why I needed to make my node/express server use express's download API, which converted the zip file in to an ArrayBuffer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `angularjs` that you are receiving a binary file in your `$http.get` or `$http.post` method. Use `{responseType : 'arraybuffer'}`.

For example:

```
$http.post('/pdf/link', requestData, { responseType : 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (data, status, headers) {

        headers = data.headers();
        var contentType = headers['content-type'];
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');

        try {
            var blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);

            linkElement.setAttribute("download", "mypdf.pdf");

            var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                "view": window,
                "bubbles": true,
                "cancelable": false
            });

            linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This can be improved by the following lines: `linkElement.href = url;
      linkElement.download = 'file.pdf';
      linkElement.click();`

Answer (score 0):

Just change it from your html:

```
<a target="_self" href="example.com/uploads/file.pdf" download="file_new_name.pdf">
```

Comment: That would work if the file wasn't behind a secure REST API.

Comment: what if you set the header: $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w';

Comment: No, it's much more complicated than that. We're integrated with Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

Check encoding with your api and in this lines, this worked for me:

```
            var filepdf = Base64.encode(response.data);
            $scope.filepdf = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfdata;
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
    $scope.pdfDownloads = function() {
        DownloadPath.get({id: $rootScope.user.account_id}, function (data) {
            $scope.createtext = "Download PDF file";
            $scope.download_pdf_filename = data.filename;
            $scope.getPdf = true;
            $scope.download_dir = file_url;

            $http.get($scope.download_dir).then(function (response) {
                var pdfdata= Base64.encode(response.data);
                $scope.pdfdata= 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfdata;
                $('#pdfanchor').attr({
                    href: $scope.pdfdata,
                    download: $scope.download_pdf_filename
                })
            });                    
        });
    };
```

***HTML***

```
<a href=""ng-click="pdfDownloads()" >Download</a>
```

***EDIT:***
***THIS IS HOW WE STRUCTURED THE RESPONSE (PHP functions)***

```
contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
contentDescription = 'File Transfer';
contentDisposition = 'attachment; filename=' . basename(file_nae);
expires = 0;
cacheControl = 'must-revalidate';
contentLength = filesize($file_name);
body =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_name));
```

Comment: That would work if we base64 encoded the file before we sent it, but we don't. The file is a raw (binary) pdf file.

Comment: But that can be done right? just encode before response?? :|

Comment: Honestly this was a hussle for me, in the end we decided to change the api response.... not ideal

Comment: thanks for the answer, hope you solve it... will check back, cheers