# Save response as file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, download, httpresponse

I have WebAPI method which returns `HttpResponseMessage` with `.csv` file as Content:

```
private static HttpResponseMessage FileAsAttachment(string file)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    result.Content = new StringContent(file);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment"); //attachment will force download
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = string.Format("Report-{0}.csv", now.ToString("MMMM"));

    return result;
}
```

So I have just click function, which make call to server :

```
$scope.GenerateReport = function() {
     var endDate = '2016-04-30';
     UserDaysSummary.generateReport({endDate: endDate }, function (result) {
          console.log("Export");
     });
}
```

But all that I've got - is a response with data inside. 
I've tried to get it as file using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442914/3917754) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448640/3917754) answer, but this doesn't change anything.

Preferably, that call to the server has `GET` method, btw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is your `GenerateReport` function returning a promise?  Try this:

```
userDaysSummary.generateReport = function(endDate) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get('path/to/api', { endDate: endDate }, { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var results = {
            data: data, //your file is here
            headers: headers(), //headers are here
            status: status,
            config: config
        };

        //return a success promise containing the response object
        defer.resolve(results);

    }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
        defer.reject(data);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

**Then, using the promise to download the file:**

```
userDaysSummary.generateReport(endDate).then(function(response) {
    //get the file
    var octetStreamMime = 'application/octet-stream';

    //get the headers' content disposition
    var cd = response.headers["content-disposition"];

    //get the file name with regex
    var regex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    var match = regex.exec(cd);

    //is there a fiel name?
    var fileName = match[1] || "myDefaultFileName.csv";

    //replace leading and trailing slashes that C# added to your file name
    fileName = fileName.replace(/\"/g, "");

    //determine the content type from the header or default to octect stream
    var contentType = response.headers["content-type"] || octetStreamMime;

    //finally, download it
    try {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: contentType});

        //downloading the file depends on the browser
        //IE handles it differently than chrome/webkit
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(objectUrl);
        }
    } catch (exc) {
        console.log("Save Blob method failed with the following exception.");
        console.log(exc);
    }

}, function(error) {
    //an error occurred while trying the API, handle this
});
```

Comment: 2 Comments - it want to generate report before I click on button and I get error `angular.js:11655 TypeError: headers is not a function`

Comment: I used the following to get the headers. rest of the code works, thanks. 
`var contentType =  response.headers()["content-type"];`