# Save files from API Url Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Web API end point which returns location of URL (http://somedomain.com/myproj/reports/dailystock.pdf).

A button is click, then this API gets called, url is returned).It might be PDF or XL or Word file too

How can i want to download the file (save on) to disk using JavaScript (AngularJs).

At present, I open the file in new window (tab).

Comment: Opening the file in a new window should open the download popup unless the browser have a builtint viewer. Why does `window.open()` not sufice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

Add this as a dependency to your module

```
.module('module', ['ngFileSaver'])
```

Use it like

```
 $http.post('YourAPIURL', {optionsObject}, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  .success(function(data) {
            var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            saveAs(file, 'filename.pdf');
        });
```

Read [here](http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215049/how-to-download-file-using-angularjs-and-calling-mvc-api) would also be useful